# Are we requiring code too often?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, code

Earlier today I posted a question which, I feel, doesn't require code. It's a general knowledge sort of question, rather than one specific to faulty code. Granted, the question came about because I had some code that wasn't working, but that's because I'm doing something I've never done before and am unfamiliar with.

The question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17799985/if-statement-in-java-in-mathematica).

The question has received comments requesting for code and I assume the downvotes are also because of an omission of code. I don't know that this is entirely fair since, as I said, this is a general knowledge question - I'm not supplying code because I don't want an explanation of why a certain bit of code isn't working, I'm looking for an answer to a question.

So, are we requiring code too often? Has the expectation that people include their code in their questions become too stringent that we don't respond to questions that don't necessarily need code? Do we, in fact, actually not want questions if they don't include specific pieces of code?

Comment: Please don't assume that there's a general problem or conspiracy afoot just based on a single, isolated incident. *In general*, providing code with your question is a good idea. And animuson is probably right, based on the original wording of your question, people were looking for the code. Also keep in mind that your question looks very simple, and given the quantity of bad questions we get per-minute on SO, people (right or wrong) may have judged it by its cover. Your question wasn't closed, you just got some comments. Explaining yourself there would've been sufficient. Or just posting code.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't disagree with what you're saying, but I'm not sure that this is an isolated incident. Though I can't link to a list of examples, it's been my experience that people are often asked for code far more often than necessary - many times the question should be answerable without code. I felt a discussion on whether we really need to be seeing code as often as we ask for it was a legitimate one for the meta.

Answer (score 8):

Well, your original question referenced specific code that wasn't working as expected. You jumped to the conclusion that it was about using Java vs Mathematica syntax. What makes you so sure that is even the problem? It's unclear from the question how your problem even relates to the question you're asking as an end result. Have you tried using the other one to see if it works?

The key phrase in there is **have you tried**. No, code is not always required, but we do need more to go off than "My if statement isn't working. Am I doing it the wrong way?"

Comment: He actually doesn't say he has a problem... he says the question is regarding some code he's writing. To assume he is having a problem misses the point of the question: syntax practice.

Comment: @D80Buckeye: *"In this Java code is an If statement, and right now it's not doing what it's supposed to do."* - Indicates a problem.

Comment: so you're running with the original, unedited question. got it.

Comment: Well, that's what sparked his now edited question, and is what sparked the comments requesting code. The edited question honestly still doesn't make much sense. I agree with Nathaniel's comment on the question - try them both and see which works. He's still missing the "What have you tried?" component.

Comment: @Animuson The thing is that I'm certain that I would be able to figure out what's wrong with the code if I knew for certain what the proper syntax was. If I knew I had the right syntax and it still wasn't working then posting code would be appropriate. But right now it's not a question of "why isn't my code working", it's "what is the right code to use in this case".

Comment: @MattS: Seeing the code you tried can make it much clearer what you're *trying* to do, which in turn makes it easier to tell what the correct syntax is.

Comment: @David Robinson Except it's quite simple what I'm trying to do: write an If-Then statement in Java in Mathematica using JLink. The specifics of the If-Then are irrelevant.

Answer (score -6):

This has happened to me before. I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779852/google-maps-direction-renderer-removes-existing-markers/) yesterday. I did not think it really needed the code because I was sure there was a one-word solution. Obviously there should be a simple option that would suppress the marker. I just didn't find it on gmap3 documentation (which is really short, btw).

I didn't really see the need for code. Anybody who's used `DirectionsRenderer` ought to be in on the little secret. Code would only confuse people in this case as 50 lines of code won't really do much towards a trivial option.

Comment: I see that you've posted an answer to your own question. And I couldn't help but notice that it is longer than one word.

Comment: see the comments. The answer is actually one line: suppressMarkers:true. The guy asked me to upload the code, So i acceeded. MY code is quite useless. The trick is that one attribute

Comment: 6 downvotes, 1 comment

Comment: Do you really need all 6 downvoters to leave an "I disagree with this answer" comment? Because I can just post that 6 times if it would make you feel better. That's what downvotes *mean* on Meta. (Also, I'm not one of the downvoters. My only purpose is to leave snarky comments.)

Comment: Not one of them said why they disagree with the point of view.